# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

Hi All i'm developping a game when i run it on chrome it works but when i try it on the emulator i'm getting an error in my javascript code that i can't understand the source or the cause

here's the error:

```
05-13 11:53:11.726: E/Web Console(790): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $ at file:///android_asset/www/js/html5games.matchgame6.js:5
```

the error is in line 5: here's my javascript file content:

```
  var matchingGame = {};
  ***var uiPlay1 = $("#gamePlay1");***  //////line 5
  var uiPlay2 = $("#gamePlay2");
  var uiIntro = $("#popup");
  var uiExit = $("#gameExit");
  var uiNextLevel = $("#gameNextLevel");
  var uigameQuit =$("#gameQuit");
 var uiPlay3 = $("#gamePlay3");
 matchingGame.savingObject = {};

 matchingGame.savingObject.deck = [];

 matchingGame.savingObject.removedCards = [];

 // store the counting elapsed time.
  matchingGame.savingObject.currentElapsedTime = 0;

  //store the last-elapsed-time

//matchingGame.savingObject.LastElapsedTime = 0;//now


  // store the player name
  matchingGame.savingObject.palyerName=$("#player-name").html();
  matchingGame.savingObject.currentLevel="game6.html";
  // all possible values for each card in deck
matchingGame.deck = [
'cardAK', 'cardAK',
'cardAQ', 'cardAQ',
'cardAJ', 'cardAJ',

  ];

   $(  function(){init();}  );


  //initialise game
   function init() {


                    $("#game").addClass("hide");

                    $("#cards").addClass("hide");


                   uiPlay1.click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

            $("#popup").addClass("hide");
            startNewGame();


             });

                uiPlay2.click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                $("#popup").addClass("hide");
                        var savedObject = savedSavingObject();
               // location.href =savedObject.currentLevel ;

                if (savedObject.currentLevel=="game6.html")
                 rejouer();
                 else 
                 location.href =savedObject.currentLevel ;

                //ResumeLastGame();
                //alert ("level :"+savedObject.currentLevel );

                });

            uiExit.click(function(e) {e.preventDefault();
                                     //alert("u clicked me ");
                                    }
                        );



                uiPlay3.click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#popupHelp").fadeIn(500, function() {
                $(this).delay(10000).fadeOut(500)}); });


    }
```

Any idea please thank u in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably didn't include jQuery.

Comment: Thank you guys i forget jQuery.js file u really made my Day :))

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you haven't defined the `$` function anywhere.

Perhaps you a working from documentation that assumes you have loaded [Prototype.js](http://www.prototypejs.org/), [Mootools](http://mootools.net/), [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or one of the many other libraries that set up a variable of that [(very poor) name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting).

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have loaded jquery, mootools, other javascript libraries etc  before you use the `$`.

Have you included your library at the end of your document and you have your script written before the library is downloaded.

make sure you have a script tag that refers to your library and then have your script content.

Also one more thing to note is that your document may not have been loaded when your scriot is executed and some of the controls might not exist on the page, thus make sure you wrap them in an API that will run the function once the document is loaded completely. In jquery you use `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Answer (score -1):

I am developing a JS app in Ejecta.   jQuery was included but the DOM ready doesn't work with Ejecta.   Instead on site/app initialization I do something like this:

```
function func() {
    init();
    animate();
}

setTimeout(func, 1000);
```

This gives jQuery time to be loaded and parsed.